# How do you /setblock a sign on a wall in 1.14.4?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have tried using wall_sign and oak_wall_sign but I have had no luck. I am on Java 1.14.4, any help please?

Comment: What happens instead? Pops off the wall, error message, your computer explodes, …? And unrelated: Why are you in 1.14.4? 1.15.2 has a ton of bug fixes, performance improvements and no downsides. Depending on what exact problem you really have, it might even already be fixed in that version.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
/setblock ~ ~ ~ minecraft:oak_wall_sign[facing=north]
```

You can also specify the rotation using the **facing** block state. More info on that: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sign#Block_states